# Simple HTML DOM Parser не видит объекта

Tags: php, html, синтаксический-анализ

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с проблемой. Simple HTML DOM Parser видит не все теги на странице. Не находит айдишник "landingImage", хотя он 100% есть (смотрел через код страницы).

Код:

```
<?php

include ('library/simple_html_dom.php');

    $html = new simple_html_dom(); //создаём новый объект
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.amazon.com/Versace-Womens-23C935D002-S535-Display/dp/B00J5D4NOM/ref=sr_1_56?s=apparel&ie=UTF8&qid=1414880469&sr=1-56');

foreach($html->find('img') as $img) {
 echo $img->id.'<br />';
}
?>
```

**Обновление**

Убрал переопределение, но результат не изменился. Нужная мне информация содержится в свойстве `data-a-dynamic-image` изображения с айди `landingImage, simple_html_dom.php` позволяет вытаскивать значения свойств, но почему-то не получается найти именно этот тег `<img>`, это может быть связанно с тем, что его src содержит 25 тысяч знаков? И что с этим делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы тут переоределили переменную, почитайте про классы и объекты в php.

```
$html = new simple_html_dom(); //создаём новый объект
$html = file_get_html('http://www.amazon.com/Versace-Womens-23C935D002-S535-Display/dp/B00J5D4NOM/ref=sr_1_56?s=apparel&ie=UTF8&qid=1414880469&sr=1-56');
```

Через код страницы смотреть бесполезно. Все работает на javascript и ajax. А чтобы получить хотя бы страницу, необходимо отправлять правильные заголовки (так же, как это делает браузер).

Amazon очень постарался, чтобы их не могли легко распарсить, потренируйтесь сначала на сайтах попроще. :)